# Flow on a Torus is Transitive iff it is Incommensurate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, integrable-systems

Consider the system
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=\mathbf{a}
$$
where $t\in\mathbb{R},\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ and $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n.$
It is well known that the flow on the n-torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ generated by 
$$\varphi_t:\mathbb{T}^n\to\mathbb{T}^n
$$
given by 
$$\varphi_t\left(\mathbf{x}_0\right):=t\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{x}_0
$$
is transitive if and only if it is incommensurate.
This paper

http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/FE/FE_pdf_with_bookmark/FE01-10-en_KML/fe07-091-102/fe07-091-102.pdf

references several papers early on as a proof of this. However, I'm looking for a direct proof that doesn't rely on any measure theoretic notions or ergodic theory for pedagogical purposes. I think I have a proof, yet I haven't been able find one anywhere else despite this being an important example in integrable dynamical systems. Has anyone come across a direct proof of this well-known result?

Comment: in dimension 2 there is Kronecker's theorem, in Diophantine Approximations by Niven. In the chapter notes he sys that , for $1, \alpha, \beta$ linearly independent over the rationals, the images of $m \alpha, m \beta$ in the unit square  are both dense and uniformly distributed. Here we go, dimension $n$ is in Cassels (1957), chapter 4.

Comment: I would also like to see an answer to this question. You mentioned that you have a direct proof: can you share?